# dotnetnuke stop personabar sliding

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I'm running the free DNN platform 9.0.1 and I would like to stop the left personabar from sliding into view left to right. I want it to be static and visible from the moment I refresh the page. I tried adding CSS to override the 'left' property but it didn't help. Where's the JavaScript code that's performing the slide? I want to remove it.

Comment: I believe this is built into the core of the modern DNN framework and there isn't a setting to allow for this to stop.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it. If anyone else is bothered by it, here's how you can stop the animation.

In '/DesktopModules/admin/Dnn.PersonaBar/scripts/main.js', I changed the following:

```
$personaBar.css({ left: -100 });
$parentBody.animate({ marginLeft: personaBarMenuWidth }, 200, 'linear', onShownPersonaBar);
$personaBar.animate({ left: 0 }, 200, 'linear', callback);
```

to...

```
//$personaBar.css({ left: -100 });
//$parentBody.animate({ marginLeft: personaBarMenuWidth }, 0, 'linear', onShownPersonaBar);
//$personaBar.animate({ left: 0 }, 0, 'linear', callback);

onShownPersonaBar();
callback();
```

...and I changed the '.personabar' rule in the CSS to have a 'left:0;'.